# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I'm experimenting with Spring, Camel and ActiveMQ to simulate simple messaging pattern with two distinct JMS brokers. Here is the route I'm trying to use.

```
@Component("testRouteBuilder")
public class CamelRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jmscf2")
    private ConnectionFactory jmsServer2;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer://foo?delay=2000")
            .setBody(simple("hello"))
            .log("request: ${body}")
            .to("bean://jmsbean")
            .log("reply: ${body}");

        from("jms1://queue:dest")
            .log("got message: ${body}")
            .log("headers: ${headers}")
            .setBody(constant("reply"))
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                    Connection connection = jmsServer2.createConnection();
                    connection.start();
                    Session session = connection.createSession(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                    TextMessage inMsg = arg0.getIn().getBody(TextMessage.class);
                    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(inMsg.getJMSReplyTo());
                    TextMessage outMsg = session.createTextMessage();
                    outMsg.setJMSCorrelationID(inMsg.getJMSCorrelationID());
                    outMsg.setText("reply");
                    producer.send(outMsg);
                    session.close();
                    connection.close();
                }
            });
    }

    @Component("jmsbean")
    public static class JmsBean {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("jmscf1")
        ConnectionFactory jmsServer1;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("jmscf2")
        ConnectionFactory jmsServer2;

        public String testJms(@Body String body) throws JMSException {

            Connection conn = jmsServer1.createConnection();
            conn.start();
            Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            Connection conn2 = jmsServer2.createConnection();
            conn2.start();
            Session session2 = conn2.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            TemporaryQueue tempQueue = session2.createTemporaryQueue();

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setJMSCorrelationID("tuomas");
            message.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
            message.setJMSMessageID("tuomas");

            Queue dest = session.createQueue("dest");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(dest);
            producer.send(message);

            session.close();
            conn.close();

            MessageConsumer consumer = session2.createConsumer(tempQueue, "tuomas");
            Message reply = consumer.receive();

            session2.close();
            conn2.close();

            return reply.getBody(String.class);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the bean components

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/app-ctx.xml")
public class BeanDeclarations {


    @Autowired
    private CamelContext ctx;

    @Bean("jms1")
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("jms1Component")
    public JmsComponent jms1Component() {
        return JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(jms1());
    }

    @Bean("jms2")
    @Qualifier("jms2Component")
    public JmsComponent jms2Component() {
        return JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(jms2());
    }

    @Bean("jmscf1")
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("jmscf1")
    public ConnectionFactory jms1() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:7777");
    }

    @Bean("jmscf2")
    @Qualifier("jmscf2")
    public ConnectionFactory jms2() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:7778");
    }

    @Bean
    public Object propertiesComponent() {
        PropertiesComponent component = ctx.getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
        component.setLocation("classpath://application.properties");
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Trying to run the following example produces the following error

```
2018-04-07 15:34:55.554  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.21.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2018-04-07 15:34:55.554  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy        : JMX is enabled
2018-04-07 15:34:55.704  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.converter.DefaultTypeConverter   : Type converters loaded (core: 193, classpath: 11)
2018-04-07 15:34:55.867  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2018-04-07 15:34:55.929  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: timer://foo?delay=2000
2018-04-07 15:34:56.054  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Users\Tuomas\Desktop\springcamel\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB]
2018-04-07 15:34:56.085  INFO 7080 --- [  JMX connector] o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext       : JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
2018-04-07 15:34:56.132  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase       : KahaDB is version 6
2018-04-07 15:34:56.179  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.a.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl  : PListStore:[C:\Users\Tuomas\Desktop\springcamel\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage] started
2018-04-07 15:34:56.320  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.3 (localhost, ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-55150-1523104496195-0:1) is starting
2018-04-07 15:34:56.398  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.3 (localhost, ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-55150-1523104496195-0:1) started
2018-04-07 15:34:56.398  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
2018-04-07 15:34:56.398  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://localhost started
2018-04-07 15:34:56.429  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route2 started and consuming from: jms1://queue:dest
2018-04-07 15:34:56.429  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2018-04-07 15:34:56.429  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.21.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.875 seconds
2018-04-07 15:34:56.460  INFO 7080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-04-07 15:34:56.460  INFO 7080 --- [           main] t.springcamel.SpringcamelApplication     : Started SpringcamelApplication in 6.249 seconds (JVM running for 11.311)
2018-04-07 15:34:58.431  INFO 7080 --- [2 - timer://foo] route1                                   : request: hello
2018-04-07 15:34:58.476  INFO 7080 --- [sConsumer[dest]] route2                                   : got message: 
2018-04-07 15:34:58.476  INFO 7080 --- [sConsumer[dest]] route2                                   : headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1523104493101-0-2, JMSCorrelationID=tuomas, JMSCorrelationIDAsBytes=tuomas, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=queue://dest, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-55150-1523104496195-4:2:1:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=temp-queue://ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-55150-1523104496195-6:1:1, JMSTimestamp=1523104498460, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null}
2018-04-07 15:34:58.491 ERROR 7080 --- [sConsumer[dest]] o.a.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-55150-1523104496195-4:2:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1523104493101-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1523104493101-0-2]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route2            ] [route2            ] [jms1://queue:dest                                                             ] [        15]
[route2            ] [log3              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route2            ] [log4              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route2            ] [setBody2          ] [setBody[constant{reply}]                                                      ] [         0]
[route2            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x6da9dde8                                                          ] [        15]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1523104493101-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:66) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113) [camel-jms-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:744) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:704) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1173) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1165) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1062) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(I)Ljavax/jms/Session;
    at tuomas.springcamel.configuration.camel.CamelRouteBuilder$1.process(CamelRouteBuilder.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2018-04-07 15:34:58.491  WARN 7080 --- [sConsumer[dest]] o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener      : Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException - Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1523104493101-0-2]]

org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1523104493101-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:66) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113) ~[camel-jms-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:744) ~[spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:704) ~[spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1173) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1165) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1062) [spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(I)Ljavax/jms/Session;
    at tuomas.springcamel.configuration.camel.CamelRouteBuilder$1.process(CamelRouteBuilder.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Why I can't create the ActiveMQ Session in the Camel processor, but in the bean I can? Does this have something to do with how Spring proxies the ConnectionFactory, bug in the camel or misconfiguration of the ActiveMQ broker?

Comment: AbstractMethodError
java.lang.Object
java.lang.Throwable
java.lang.Error
java.lang.LinkageError
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
AbstractMethodError
extends IncompatibleClassChangeError
Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled. So you have a dependencies problem, verify duplicate java-ee-api jar or versions

Comment: I figured out the problem, please see the answer

Answer (score 5):

The solution was to fix the following line

`Session session = connection.createSession(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`

to

`Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`

Seems like ActiveMQ is incompatible with the JMS API in use

Comment: ActiveMQ JMS client is a JMS v1.1 based client so you must only use those APIs

Comment: If you want to use an ActiveMQ broker which supports JMS 2 then check out [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/).